# How to retrieve uncategorized emails using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph to retrieve the emails from the shared mailbox, I know how to retrieve the emails based on categories using below query.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$filter=categories/any(c:c eq 'Yellow category')
```

However I want to retrieve all the emails or count of all the emails which don't have any categories assigned. I tried using the above query in other way as

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$filter=categories/any(c:c ne 'Yellow category')
```

and also like as below, but its not working.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$filter=categories/any()
```

How can I achieve this?

Any help or pointers are appreciated.

Comment: No, there is no way as of now to filter out the empty arrays. You should get the data and filter it on your end by writing code.

Comment: Thank you Shiva for your reply.